# No such file or directory: /sys/kernel/debug/usb/usbmon/

Tags: linux-mint, usb, monitoring, wireshark

I am trying to install wiresahrk on my linux mint 19.2 machine.
When executing as root it says:

```
The capture session could not be initiated on interface 'usbmon1' (Can't open USB bus file /sys/kernel/debug/usb/usbmon/1t: Permission denied).
```

When executing as normal user, it just says permission denied, because i have no access to `debug`.

So why is this directory/ not available?
I come until usb then the usbmon directory does not exist. i installed it from the apt package.

How can i fix this?

Comment: Thank you. That worked, can you add as answer so i can mark as solved?

Answer (score 1):

`modprobe usbmon` as root.

Then if OK add it to `/etc/modules`.